# Taylor of $f:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$

Tags: taylor-expansion

My notes say the following: You have a function $D(x, y, \sigma)$ mapping to a scaler. Take the taylor expension (which I can only do for functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$) up to the quadratic terms. So this is what I should get.

$D(x) = D + \frac{\delta D^T}{\delta x}x + \frac{1}{2}x^T\frac{\delta^2D}{\delta x^2} x$.

I see things like the factorial in the denominator but thats about it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansion in the section Taylor series in several variables and combining that with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform in section Keypoint localization gives the answer to my question.